# How to rigorously prove this result on limits of a function of two variables?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function, let $(a, b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, and let $L \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that 
$\lim_{ (x,y) \to (a, b) } f(x, y)$ exists and equals $L$, and suppose also that the one-dimensional limits $\lim_{x \to a} f(x, y)$ and $\lim_{y \to b} f(x, y)$ both exist. Then how to prove that the two iterated limits $\lim_{x \to a} \left[ \lim_{y \to b} f(x, y) \right]$ and $\lim_{ y \to b } \left[ \lim_{ x \to  a } f(x, y) \right]$ both exist and that we have the following result?
$$ \lim_{x \to a} \left[ \lim_{y \to b} f(x, y) \right] = \lim_{ y \to b} \left[ \lim_{ x \to a } f(x, y) \right] = L.$$

My Attempt:

> Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. Then we can find a real number $\delta > 0$ such that 
>   $$ \left\lvert f(x, y) - L \right\rvert < \varepsilon $$
>   for all $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ for which 
>   $$ 0 < \sqrt{ (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 } < \delta. $$
>
> Let $\phi \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\psi \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the functions defined by 
>   $$ \phi(x) = \lim_{y \to b} f(x, y) \ \mbox{ for all } \ x \in \mathbb{R}, $$
>   and 
>   $$\psi(y) = \lim_{x \to a} f(x, y) \ \mbox{ for all } \ y \in \mathbb{R}. $$
>
> Now we need to show that $\lim_{x \to a } \phi(x)$ and $\lim_{y \to b} \psi(y)$ both exist and that 
>   $$ \lim_{x \to a } \phi(x) = L = \lim_{y \to b} \psi(y). $$

How to proceed from here?

Comment: Do you assume that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f(x, y)$ exists for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Adayah yes, that's how it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beginning is OK. Now, in order to prove by definition that

$$\lim_{x \to a} \phi(x) = L,$$

it suffices to show that the neighborhood $|x-a| < \delta$ is correct for the chosen $\varepsilon > 0$.

Fix $x_0$ such that $|x_0 - a| < \delta$. Then there is a $\delta' > 0$ such that

$$\{ x_0 \} \times (b - \delta', b + \delta') \subseteq B( (a, b), \delta),$$

so in the neighborhood $(b-\delta', b+\delta')$ of $b$ we have $|f(x_0, y) - L| < \varepsilon$, hence $|\phi(x_0) - L| \leqslant \varepsilon$.

The second part is done in a symmetrical fashion.